# Spring @Component annotation on both Parent and Child class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on a spring boot application where I have a Parent and a Child class where Child extends Parent class. I am using `@Component` annotation for both the classes so as to be able to manage their instances by Spring.

```
@Component
public class Parent {}

@Component
public class Child extends Parent{}
```

This results in a `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException`
`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.Parent' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: Parent,Child`

Using `@Primary` on the Parent class solves the issue but am wondering what is the best practice or recommended way to follow in the above scenario?

Edit: The Parent class already exists and is being injected in multiple classes already using `@Resource(type = Parent.class)`. I am adding the Child class newly and would prefer to not modify the existing code as much as possible.

Comment: Ultimately, I believe that your model is incorrect.  Does it make sense that every Child is a Parent?   Every child HAS a parent, but not every child IS A parent.  Read up on favoring composition over inheritance.

Comment: @lane.maxwell - In my use case, Parent class has 'X' behavior and Child class has 'X+Y' behavior. Based on the type of request I need to decide if 'X' or 'X+Y' . Does it not make sense to use inheritance in such a scenario?

Comment: I would not use inheritance for this; I would use composition.  There isn't enough space in these comments to elaborate on why composition is a better approach, and it's off-topic for the question, so it doesn't warrant an answer, but take some time exploring Google for `composition over inheritance`.  Define an interface that contains the behavior you want from the Parent, have the Parent implement that interface, and inject that Interface into your Child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see you have two beans of same type so spring is unable to differntaiate which one to inject first . As per solution you said is right we can use @primary annotation as well to solve this issue. By tht spring will be able to undersatnd which one is primary or which one should be injected first . or we can use @Autowire under @qualifer annotaion to specify which bean name you want to inject.

Answer (score 0):

make Parent class abstract:

```
@Component
public abstract class Parent {}

@Component
@Profile("profileOneName")
public class ChildProfileOne extends Parent{}

@Component
@Profile("profileTwoName")
public class ChildProfileTwo extends Parent{}
```

Comment: The Parent class is a concrete class and it's instance is already being used in the application. Edited the question to add this info.

Comment: add @Profile("profileName") to Child class. and use Parent or Child (depending on the profile).  It is not possible to use two beans with the same name.